# .val() doesn't trigger event onchange on external script

Tags: jquery, events, triggers, onchange

i found this colorpicker http://pastebin.com/17cPkjAT
my problem is that if set the text to the input box through jquery the colorpicker won't "hear" the new text.

Example:

1. I set the color to black using the mouse
2. I set the color to white through jquery

and the only thing that changes is the text, not the color, result:

[image]

Comment: That seems logical to me. The `onchange` event should only be triggered by user input. One hackish way to get about this is to use a timer to check for updates. Not the prettiest, but effective. (A "better" way would be to attach to a notification of the color being picked in the dialog and launch all required actions in there.)

Comment: I think the canonical answer here is that onchange() is only automatically fired when a *user* changes it; otherwise you'll need to call it yourself.

Comment: Anyway, when i call .change() nothing happens... so what should i put on the timer callback?

Answer (score 4):

Call `.change()` after updating the value:

```
$(selector).val("#FFFFFF").change();
```

Comment: There is another method you can call to set the color `.ColorPickerSetColor()` per the documentation.  You'll need to post your code and/or create a jsfiddle in order for us to help with any specific issues you are experiencing.

Comment: Sorry, i posted the wrong colorpicker, the one i'm using hasn't this function!
http://pastebin.com/17cPkjAT